# Python not inserting an EOF character after file close?

Tags: python

I'm having a strange problem where some Python code that prints to a file is not inserting an EOF character. Basically, the Python script generates runscripts to later be submitted as jobs on a cluster. I essentially wrote the entire runscript between """'s, allowing for variables to be plugged in (to vary some parameters in my simulation). I write the runscripts using the

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as runscrpt:
    runscrpt.write("""ENTIRE_FILE_CONTENTS_HERE""")
```

syntax. I can give the actual code if necessary but it's not much more than above. Despite the script running fine and generating all of my runsripts, whenever I submitted them nothing happened. It took me a long time to figure out why, but it's because they're missing an EOF character. I can fix it by, for example, opening one, adding some trailing whitespace or a blank line somewhere in vim, and resaving the file.

Why isn't Python inserting the EOF character, and is there a better way to fix this than manually making trivial edits to all the files with vim?

Comment: There are no 'EOF characters' in files on most systems, though DOS-based systems sometimes use control-Z to indicate the end of the material in a text file.  What are you expecting to find?  Do make sure the last line of material ends with an appropriate line-ending sequence (newline on Unix, CRLF on Windows).  Don't forget that the file may not be written completely until you close the output file.

Comment: the "with-as" syntax automatically closes the file, does it not?

Basically, say I modify a runscript in vim, save and close, open it, and then remove the modification. The "edited" file will work, but the original one will not. Using the "diff" command will note that the first is missing an EOF character at the end, whereas the second is not.

Comment: The `with ... as` syntax might well close the file automatically; it still remains true that not all the output necessarily appears until the file is closed, but the closure may be 'immediate'. However, that simply means that we need to understand what you mean by 'not inserting an EOF character' because, as I stated up front, on most systems, there is no such thing as an EOF character, notwithstanding what you think a terminal takes/generates as an 'EOF character'. (If you need x-refs to questions where that is explained in detail, shout -- I'll find some of my cogent answers about it).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you mean there is no EOL (not EOF!) at the end, because that's what `diff` will typically tell you.  Just add a newline at the end of the write (make sure there is a newline before the final `"""` terminator, or write a separate newline explicitly).

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as runscript:
    runscript.write("""ENTIRE_FILE_CONTENTS_HERE\n""")
```

(As a bonus, I added the missing vowel.)